# gstreamer problem

Tags: vlc, libcamera, gstreamer

I want to try gstreamer to do live video streaming with VLC player.

- Raspberry pi 4 model B.
- Bookworm OS, 32 Bit
- Linux raspberrypi 6.1.0-rpi4-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.54-1+rpt2 (2023-10-05) aarch64 GNU/Linux
- Camera Module 2

Before this, I use RSTP to do live video streaming. RSTP got delay between 1.5s to 3s delay.
I follow this link for RSTP :- https://davidmays.io/streaming-raspberry-pi-video-via-rtsp-with-gstreamer-and-video4linux/
During doing RSTP, I use Bulleyes OS 64bit.

Now, I use bookworm OS, 32bit.
I follow this step, but did not success. https://qengineering.eu/install-gstreamer-1.18-on-raspberry-pi-4.html
.Maybe because of OS.

I install the gstreamer library base on this link:- https://qengineering.eu/install-gstreamer-1.18-on-raspberry-pi-4.html

1. $ sudo apt-get install libx264-dev libjpeg-dev
2. $ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev \ libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \ libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev \ gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \ gstreamer1.0-tools \ gstreamer1.0-gl \ gstreamer1.0-gtk3
3. $ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3
4. $ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio

Next I follow this step, for gstreamer sub-topic USING GSTREAMER. https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html#using-gstreamer

Terminal 1 command:-

1. $ libcamera-vid -t 0 -n --inline -o - | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc fd=0 ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000

For the client (type this into another terminal command)

1. $ gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc address=localhost port=5000 ! h264parse ! v4l2h264dec ! autovideosink

The video camera is showing.

But, I cannot use this udp://localhost:500 on VLC Player.
Did I miss step?

Comment: `but did not success` - were there any errors in any steps along the way? Those instructions are for Bullseye, so ...